# How to change this to indirect speech?

Tags: reported-speech

> She said to him, "Would you like a pizza today?"

How to change this to indirect speech?

Is it *She asked him if he would have liked a pizza that day.*?

Comment: ***would have liked*** is completely unacceptable for the cited context. ***would like*** is fine, but in practice I think an awful lot of native speakers would transparently simplify to *She asked if he **wanted** a pizza that day.*

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a mechanical transformation to indirect speech.  When reporting speech it is common to leave out details that are irrelevant to the story that your are telling.

So I'd report this as "She asked him if he'd like pizza" Or, if we are reporting on a fact, not on the exact words used "She asked him if he wanted pizza."

This omits the bit about "today". I'm omitting that because it's not important to the story I want to tell. If I did need to include it I'd include something to show that she meant "on that day".  But there are numerous ways to say this "on that day" is one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

"Would" does not change when we move from direct speech to indirect speech.

> She asked whether he would like a pizza that day.

Comment: Or _would have liked_?

Comment: _He would have liked a pizza_ suggests that he got something else but would rather have had pizza.

Comment: So, _She asked him if/whether he would like a pizza that day_ @Kate Bunting?

Comment: We definitely cannot say "would have liked" because that would negate the action.

Comment: Yes, as Patriot has already told you.